# How do I append text to each line of output depending on the results of this bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm using this bash script to run Nmap NSE scripts against a list of IP's and it works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read server; do
    nmap --script smb-vuln-* "$server" |
    sed -n "/$server/p;/VULNERABLE:/{n;p;}" 
done <windows-servers.txt
```

Yields:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.52.27
Nmap scan report for 192.168.52.29
Nmap scan report for 192.168.52.38
Nmap scan report for 192.168.52.78
Nmap scan report for 192.168.52.224
Nmap scan report for 192.168.52.232
|   Microsoft Windows system vulnerable to remote code execution (MS08-067)
|   Remote Code Execution vulnerability in Microsoft SMBv1 servers (ms17-010)
```

But what I would like to do is append the output depending on results like so:

```
192.168.52.27 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.29 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.38 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.78 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.224 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.232 - VULNERABLE:
Microsoft Windows system vulnerable to remote code execution (MS08-067)
Remote Code Execution vulnerability in Microsoft SMBv1 servers (ms17-010)
```

Syntax is not really that important so whatever is easiest works for me. I'm a total noob and it took me hours just to get to this point. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this to your last line:

```
| tac | awk '$1=="Nmap" && last=="|"{print $NF,"- VULNERABLE:"; last=""; next} $1=="|"{last=$1; print; next} {print $NF,"- NOT vulnerable."}' | tac
```

Output:

```
192.168.52.27 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.29 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.38 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.78 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.224 - NOT vulnerable.
192.168.52.232 - VULNERABLE:
|   Microsoft Windows system vulnerable to remote code execution (MS08-067)
|   Remote Code Execution vulnerability in Microsoft SMBv1 servers (ms17-010)
```

---

See: `man tac` and [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)